# Ansible deprecation warning for undefined variable despite "when" clause

Tags: ansible

I have this in an ansible playbook:

```
- name: install custom packages for the host if there are any
    apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
    with_items: "{{ extra_packages }}"
    when: extra_packages is defined
```

Running it results in this:

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error.: 'extra_packages' is undefined.

But I'm checking if the variable is defined in the when clause. How do I fix this so that it doesn't cause a fatal error when ansible gets upgraded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution wasn't initially obvious and it does feel like an inconsistency in ansible.

```
  - name: install custom packages for the host if there are any
    apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
    with_items: "{{ extra_packages | default([]) }}"
```

Essentially, using "when" with a loop doesn't really work for this use case.

It's documented [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement):

> If you need to skip the whole task depending on the loop variable being defined, used the |default filter to provide an empty iterator

However, that piece of documentation isn't Google-able for the particular error message. This is only a problem now that the behaviour previously (unknowingly) relied upon has been deprecated.